# How to find an element in the results of "find()"?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following HTML structure.

I need to be able to build the array of attributes of `img`'s to be able to build a gallery.

So far I was able to build an array of `d2`'s using `find()`, but I seem to be unable to use `find()` on the results of `find()`, and removing `a`'s and `d3`'s also fails (see the fiddle). How to get it right?

```
<div class="d1">
   <div class="d2">
        <img src="http://s.com/x.jpg"/><div class="d3"/><a/><a/>
   </div>
   <div class="d2">
        <img src="http://s.com/y.jpg"/><div class="d3"/><a/><a/>
   </div>
   <div class="d2">
        <img src="http://s.com/z.jpg"/><div class="d3"/><a/><a/>
   </div> 
</div>
```

The output I am aiming for is either

```
<img src="http://s.com/x.jpg"/ style=\"display:none\">
<img src="http://s.com/y.jpg"/ style=\"display:none\">
<img src="http://s.com/z.jpg"/ style=\"display:none\">
```

that I will push into a hidden div or

```
["http://s.com/x.jpg",
 "http://s.com/y.jpg",
 "http://s.com/z.jpg"]
```

that I will store in a global variable.

I need this to be able to go back and forth over the images in the gallery. I am not sure which one I will use, so I wanted to be able to use both - or maybe you could tell me which approach is better?

```js
function get_images_for_gallery(an_image) {
  var all_outside_images = an_image.parent().parent().find('.outside_image');

  var result = '';
  $.each(all_outside_images, function(index, outside_image) {
    console.log("outside_image " + $(outside_image).html());
    // attempt 1 - find an img
    var img = $(outside_image).find("img");
    console.log("img " + $(img).html());
    // attempt 2 - remove a's and a div
    var no_a = $(outside_image).remove("a");
    var no_a_no_div = $(no_a).remove("div");
    console.log("no_a_no_div " + $(no_a_no_div).html());
    // add display:none
    $(no_a_no_div).attr("display", "none");
    console.log("img 2 " + $(no_a_no_div).html());
    result += $(img).html();
  });

  return result;
}

var obj = $("#logo")[0];
console.log(get_images_for_gallery($(obj)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images_center" imgheight="200">
  <div class="outside_image" style=" max-width: 146px "> <img id="logo" alt="Saint George and the Dragon, <br/>circa 1432-5, Rogier van der Weyden" caption="Saint George and the Dragon, <br/>circa 1432-5, Rogier van der Weyden" sourcename="Wikipedia Commons" sourcehrf="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rogier_van_der_Weyden_-_Saint_George_and_the_Dragon.jpg"
      src="https://www.yu51a5.org/wp-content/uploads/horsemen/Rogier_van_der_Weyden_-_Saint_George_and_the_Dragon.jpg" style=" max-height: 200px ">
    <div class="wp-caption-text" style=" max-width: 141px ">Saint George and the Dragon, <br>circa 1432-5, Rogier van der Weyden</div> <a href="https://www.yu51a5.org/wp-content/uploads/horsemen/Rogier_van_der_Weyden_-_Saint_George_and_the_Dragon.jpg" style="display:none">Invisible, to help broken links check</a>    <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rogier_van_der_Weyden_-_Saint_George_and_the_Dragon.jpg" style="display:none">Invisible, to help broken links check</a></div>
  <div class="outside_image" style=" max-width: 355px "> <img alt="St. George and the Dragon, <br/>cr. 1430-35, Paolo Uccello, Florence, Italy" caption="St. George and the Dragon, <br/>cr. 1430-35, Paolo Uccello, Florence, Italy" sourcename="The Jacquemart-André Museum" sourcehrf="https://www.musee-jacquemart-andre.com/en/oeuvres/saint-georges-and-dragon"
      src="https://www.yu51a5.org/wp-content/uploads/horsemen/uccello_st_georges.jpg" style=" max-height: 200px ">
    <div class="wp-caption-text" style=" max-width: 350px ">St. George and the Dragon, <br>cr. 1430-35, Paolo Uccello, Florence, Italy</div> <a href="https://www.yu51a5.org/wp-content/uploads/horsemen/uccello_st_georges.jpg" style="display:none">Invisible, to help broken links check</a> <a href="https://www.musee-jacquemart-andre.com/en/oeuvres/saint-georges-and-dragon"
      style="display:none">Invisible, to help broken links check</a></div>
  <div class="outside_image" style=" max-width: 437px "> <img alt="The Battle of Nineveh (between Khosrau II and Heraclius, in 627), <br/>cr. 1452-66, Piero della Francesca, Arezzo, Italy" caption="The Battle of Nineveh (between Khosrau II and Heraclius, in 627), <br/>cr. 1452-66, Piero della Francesca, Arezzo, Italy"
      sourcename="Wikipedia Commons" sourcehrf="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Piero_della_Francesca_021.jpg" src="https://www.yu51a5.org/wp-content/uploads/horsemen/Piero_della_Francesca_021.jpg" style=" max-height: 200px ">
    <div class="wp-caption-text"
      style=" max-width: 432px ">The Battle of Nineveh (between Khosrau II and Heraclius, in 627), <br>cr. 1452-66, Piero della Francesca, Arezzo, Italy</div> <a href="https://www.yu51a5.org/wp-content/uploads/horsemen/Piero_della_Francesca_021.jpg" style="display:none">Invisible, to help broken links check</a>    <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Piero_della_Francesca_021.jpg" style="display:none">Invisible, to help broken links check</a></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/yu51a5/j56Lcu94/64/)

Comment: Your code seems a lot more complicated than it needs to be. What exactly is the output you're trying to create?

Comment: `<a/>` is not valid HTML, `a` is not a void element, so it cannot be self-closing.

Comment: All you need in that case is a single `find()`: `$('.d1').find('img')` if you want the `src` attributes as an array after that you can use `map()`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - added the contents of JSFiddle to the question, thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your goal of selecting only the `img` elements, then all you need is a single jQuery object with a selector which targets them:

```
let $images = $('.outside_image img');
```

`find()` will also work if you have a reference to a parent element:

```
let $images = $someParentElement.find('img');
```

Similarly, if you want to build an array of the `src` attributes from that you can use `map()`:

```
let sources = $images.map((i, el) => el.src).get();
```

Here's a working example:

```js
let $images = $('.outside_image img');
console.log($images.length);

let sources = $images.map((i, el) => el.src).get();
console.log(sources);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images_center" imgheight="200">
  <div class="outside_image" style=" max-width: 146px "> 
    <img id="logo" alt="Saint George and the Dragon, <br/>circa 1432-5, Rogier van der Weyden" caption="Saint George and the Dragon, <br/>circa 1432-5, Rogier van der Weyden" sourcename="Wikipedia Commons" sourcehrf="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rogier_van_der_Weyden_-_Saint_George_and_the_Dragon.jpg" src="https://www.yu51a5.org/wp-content/uploads/horsemen/Rogier_van_der_Weyden_-_Saint_George_and_the_Dragon.jpg" style=" max-height: 200px">
    <div class="wp-caption-text" style="max-width: 141px">Saint George and the Dragon, <br>circa 1432-5, Rogier van der Weyden</div> 
    <a href="https://www.yu51a5.org/wp-content/uploads/horsemen/Rogier_van_der_Weyden_-_Saint_George_and_the_Dragon.jpg" style="display:none">Invisible, to help broken links check</a>
    <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rogier_van_der_Weyden_-_Saint_George_and_the_Dragon.jpg" style="display:none">Invisible, to help broken links check</a>
  </div>
  <div class="outside_image" style="max-width: 355px">
    <img alt="St. George and the Dragon, <br/>cr. 1430-35, Paolo Uccello, Florence, Italy" caption="St. George and the Dragon, <br/>cr. 1430-35, Paolo Uccello, Florence, Italy" sourcename="The Jacquemart-André Museum" sourcehrf="https://www.musee-jacquemart-andre.com/en/oeuvres/saint-georges-and-dragon" src="https://www.yu51a5.org/wp-content/uploads/horsemen/uccello_st_georges.jpg" style="max-height: 200px">
    <div class="wp-caption-text" style="max-width: 350px">St. George and the Dragon, <br>cr. 1430-35, Paolo Uccello, Florence, Italy</div> 
    <a href="https://www.yu51a5.org/wp-content/uploads/horsemen/uccello_st_georges.jpg" style="display:none">Invisible, to help broken links check</a> <a href="https://www.musee-jacquemart-andre.com/en/oeuvres/saint-georges-and-dragon" style="display:none">Invisible, to help broken links check</a>
  </div>
  <div class="outside_image" style="max-width: 437px"> 
    <img alt="The Battle of Nineveh (between Khosrau II and Heraclius, in 627), <br/>cr. 1452-66, Piero della Francesca, Arezzo, Italy" caption="The Battle of Nineveh (between Khosrau II and Heraclius, in 627), <br/>cr. 1452-66, Piero della Francesca, Arezzo, Italy" sourcename="Wikipedia Commons" sourcehrf="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Piero_della_Francesca_021.jpg" src="https://www.yu51a5.org/wp-content/uploads/horsemen/Piero_della_Francesca_021.jpg" style="max-height: 200px">
    <div class="wp-caption-text" style="max-width: 432px">The Battle of Nineveh (between Khosrau II and Heraclius, in 627), <br>cr. 1452-66, Piero della Francesca, Arezzo, Italy</div> 
    <a href="https://www.yu51a5.org/wp-content/uploads/horsemen/Piero_della_Francesca_021.jpg" style="display:none">Invisible, to help broken links check</a>    
    <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Piero_della_Francesca_021.jpg" style="display:none">Invisible, to help broken links check</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could I ask how to get html contents out of $images in your example? `console.log($images[0].innerHTML);` returns nothing.

Comment: `innerHTML` won't work as `img` elements contain no HTML. Try `outerHTML`, however getting HTML out of the DOM is a bit of a code smell. If you want to amend elements do it in the DOM directly, or if you want to copy the elements use `clone()`